# How to reuse single ViewController/"Screen-Layout" in Swift3 / Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift3

What would be the specific steps and code *(aka, the simplest possible example)* - as per best practices in Swift/Xcode - for developing a dynamic UI with the following "Hello World" implementation requirements?

> 1. Create a single view controller with a specific layout - let's say just 2 labels (First Name and State), and 2 buttons (Back and Next)
> 2. Be able to then reuse that layout as many times as necessary for a new/subsequent screen, that user can navigate to from where the user is currently at, and where the same layout components (Name and State) are updated with the content for the specific screen (in the sequence) that will be shown

Here's a screen shot of what that could like if the screens are hardcoded in the StoryBoard, where the next buttons are connected with *Show Segues*:

[image]

I am new to Swift/Xcode, coming from a background in Android development.  Studying Swift, I have not so far run across much tutorials to implement this kind of UI/UX via a dynamic approach with a reusable layout definition.  The tutorials I'm seeing seem to all require that every screen that is necessary, be explicitly added via the IDE StoryBoard

For a concrete/specific example of what I'm looking for, in Android the common way to solve for this is :

1. Create a Java class that extends Fragment, and a corresponding layout that has the 2 text labels and 2 buttons
2. For the fragment - define a constructor that takes 2 parameters: Name, State
3. Every time a new screen is needed, a new instance is generated where the contructor is called with the necessary Name and State parameters for the new view
4. The new instance is pushed onto the fragment manager instance, and that causes the new screen to load for the user
5. When user clicks Next (where next is possible), steps 3-4 are repeated for the new content

Answer (score 0):

1. Use UINavigationController and hide navigation bar.

   advantage: navigationcontroller could help you 'next' and 'back' view controllers easily.
   it's a good way for your achieve.
2. Use ContainerView.
   it's more like fragment in android.
3. Use uiview only.
   it's simple and easily.